# Can i use Mrs Eaves premium font in my logo?

Tags: fonts, logo

I have [Mrs Eaves premium font](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/emigre/mrs-eaves/). Its the same font which is used in WordPress Logo.  Can i use it in my logo?. What is premium font mean?. Do i have to purchase license for each website's logo?

Comment: That depends entirely on the kind of license the website provides, have you tried reading their faq?

Comment: The license that was purchased with the font is what is key. (I'm sure that's what you meant, but just to clarify...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Emigre's Frequently Asked Font Licensing Questions](http://www.emigre.com/FAQ.php)

> **Can I embed fonts into digital documents?**
>
> Web sites and CD-ROM titles may feature bitmap images made using our
>   fonts, but the fonts themselves may not be distributed. Embeddable
>   font formats require the duplication of the fonts and thus seriously
>   compromise the security of typefaces. The Emigre license excludes font
>   embedding, except as described in the [Embedding License Addendum](http://www.emigre.com/Embedding.php). This
>   addendum allows restricted distribution of portable digital documents
>   in Adobe Acrobat PDF format under specific circumstances.

This information is not in the licence included with the font (if you're buying from MyFonts, you can view licences from MyFonts' Buying Choices pages).

So if you already have the font, you're OK using it in a raster graphic on your sites.

But it appears you can also buy [Mrs Eaves as a Web Font](http://www.emigre.com/WebFonts/Mrs-Eaves) separately from Emigre.

I could not find any mention of any specific limitations on use within logos.

Comment: That license refers to embedding it in a PDF, not whether or not a typeface may be used as part of a logo. What defines a logo, and which type can be used varies from license to license, though most allow logo usage. A few don't though (for instance, House Industries requires separate licenses for logo usage)

Comment: You're right in that my answer deals with the implementation specifics rather than IP usage. But you do need to consider both.

Comment: Yea. Sadly fount foundries haven't really standardized on any particular language or restrictions so one usually needs to study the license of every single foundry separately. A huge pain, IMHO.